# Matlab ActiveX to Labview Vi Server, Open Vi in Project Application Instance

Tags: matlab, activex, labview

I am using Matlab on windows to control some labview vi's, with the activeX vi server. These vi's are part of a labview project. I would like to open a reference to that project instance of labview, and not the main application instance. Is this possible?

In Labview I would do this by calling: Open Application Reference.vi, and setting the vi port input / service name to that of my project. This then returns a reference to my project application instance, which I can then use to open and run the vi's.

In Matlab I am not sure how I can do the same thing. I am using the following code:

```
e = actxserver('LabVIEW.Application'); %Obtain a reference to labview vi server
vipath = full path to the vi I want to open; 
vi = invoke(e, 'GetVIReference', vipath); %Get a reference to the vi I want to open
vi.FPWinOpen = 1; %Open the front panel of the vi.
```

However, this opens the vi in the main application instance, and not in the project instance.

Hope that my question is written in an understandable way! 
Any suggestions would be great.

Also does anyone know where I can find documentation for using the labview vi server in an external program, like matlab? For example, what methods are available and how to use them?

Thanks,
labjunky

Comment: you can edit the post to fix the typo

Comment: instead of the vi, do you mean to put the full path to project?